# Grouping the date using PHP

Tags: php, date

Please Help Grouping the date (dd/mm/yyyy).
i have data like this 
`01/01/2014,02/01/2014,03/01/2014,04/02/2014,05/02/2014,07/03/2014`

i want group or want the result be like this

`1,2,3 January 2014, 04,05 Febrary 2014, 07 March 2014.`

Comment: Have you tried to do this by your self? If yes then also add your code here. We'll help you to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$raw_date = '01/01/2014,02/01/2014,03/01/2014,04/02/2014,05/02/2014,07/03/2014';
# Using DD/MM/YYYY formats strtotime understands as MM/DD/YYYY
# So replace all '/' to '-'. So strtotime understand formats as DD-MM-YYYY
$raw_date = str_replace('/', '-', $raw_date);
$separated = explode(',', $raw_date);
$collection = array();
foreach($separated as $e) {
    $e = date('j|F Y', strtotime($e));
    $e = explode('|', $e);
    if(!isset($collection[$e[1]])) {
        $collection[$e[1]] = '';
    }
    $collection[$e[1]] .= $e[0].",";
}

foreach ($collection as $my => $d) {
    echo rtrim($d, ',') . " $my\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent! @vinay-kr-sharma , but i add some more code to put my month language

```
function groupdate($dateis){
    //add my date language [ID/Indonesia]
    $monthID[1]="Januari";
    $monthID[2]="Pebruari";
    $monthID[3]="Maret";
    $monthID[4]="April";
    $monthID[5]="Mei";
    $monthID[6]="Juni";
    $monthID[7]="Juli";
    $monthID[8]="Agustus";
    $monthID[9]="September";
    $monthID[10]="Oktober";
    $monthID[11]="Nopember";
    $monthID[12]="Desember";
    $raw_date = $dateis;
    $raw_date = str_replace('/', '-', $raw_date);
    $separated = explode(',', $raw_date);
    $collection = array();
    foreach($separated as $e) {
        //Add Some code to put the my language month
        $e = date('j', strtotime($e))."|".$monthID[date('n', strtotime($e))]." ".date('Y', strtotime($e));
        $e = explode('|', $e);
        if(!isset($collection[$e[1]])) {
            $collection[$e[1]] = '';
        }
        $collection[$e[1]] .= $e[0].",";
    }
    $result="";
    foreach ($collection as $my => $d) {
        $result=$result.rtrim($d, ',') . " $my, ";
    }
    return rtrim($result, ', ');
    };
```